# Error Fix: Class 'Bridgepay\Bridge\Helper\Magento\Framework\App\State' not found

Tags: magento, magento2, payment

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I recently encountered an issue in my Magento project where the class 'Bridgepay\Bridge\Helper\Magento\Framework\App\State' was not being recognized, resulting in a fatal error. After some investigation, I discovered that the problem was in the `Helper/APIClient.php` file.

**Issue:**
The original code was:

```php
$state = $om->get(Magento\Framework\App\State::class);
```

The correct code should be:

```php
$state = $om->get(\Magento\Framework\App\State::class);
```

This change resolved the problem, and the application is now working as expected.

**Note:**

- The issue has already been fixed, and this post is for informational purposes.
- If you encounter a similar problem, make sure to check the instantiation of the mentioned class in your code.

I hope this information helps someone facing a similar issue. If you have any questions or need further clarification, please feel free to ask.

Happy coding!